# Soviet atomic bomb development — advantage of knowing it could be done, was this ever said by any Soviet scientist?

Tags: physics, nuclear-physics, cold-war, soviet-union, 20th-century

I have heard it said that even if Fuchs had not provided details which must have been invaluable — just knowing, for example, that implosion and explosive lenses were employed without any further details would have been huge — the Soviets would have had a huge advantage over allied scientists.

This would have come from the fact that they, after Hiroshima, knew that such a device could be constructed.

That certainly rings true to me — the top soviet physicists would not have had to wonder if the whole idea was crazy and that would have saved a tremendous amount of physic energy. I am looking for a quote where one of the theoreticians actually credits this as having helped them.

Comment: Implosion and lenses were only needed for plutonium. Uranium works just fine in a gun arrangement (which was not even tested before fielding).

Comment: Fuchs was not the only one.

Comment: no, but he was most important one.

Comment: @releseabe: That is very unclear. I think we do not know who was the most important one. Bohr? Oppenheimer? They certainly knew more than Fuchs.

Comment: that oppenheimer was or could have been a spy is news to me.

Comment: @releseabe:  See https://www.wilsoncenter.org/publication/was-oppenheimer-soviet-spy-roundtable-discussion.